# MySQL INSERT IN

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, count

I would like to insert the same rows but a different SIP ID number

I want the query to start say at

> 500 and go to 536

But I want to know what is the easiest way I can have a PHP script that looks at the starting number and will run the query 36 times till it reaches the number that i want it to loop

for example
$count = 36;
$start_from = 500;

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
   $sql = "INSERT INTO MYSIP VALUES (500, ****, 192.168.1.175,...)";
}
```

but then i need it to replace the 500 with 501

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
   $sql = "INSERT INTO MYSIP VALUES (501, ****, 192.168.1.175,...)";
}
```

Comment: Replace `1` with `500`, and `$count` with `536` in your for loop.

Comment: Set `$i` to your start from number... like `$i = $start_from; $i <= ($count + $start_from); $i++`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
   $sql = "INSERT INTO MYSIP VALUES (" . (500 + $i) . ", ****, 192.168.1.175,...)";
}
```

Or you could start $i at 500 and skip the addition.

Answer (score 3):

Better use it.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MYSIP VALUES ";

for ($i = $start_from; $i <= $start_from + $count; $i++) {

if($i==$start_from)
   $sql .= "({$i}, ****, 192.168.1.175,...)";
else
 $sql .= ",({$i}, ****, 192.168.1.175,...)";
}
```

So, you will have a single sql query to insert all value.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
for ($i = $start_from; $i <= $start_from + $count; $i++) {
   $sql .= "INSERT INTO MYSIP VALUES ({$i}, ****, 192.168.1.175,...);";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
for ($i = $start_from++; $i <= $start_from + $count; $i++) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MYSIP VALUES ($i, ****, 192.168.1.175,...)"; 
}
```

Because $start_from value will start from 500,so if you increment it then it will start from 501

Comment: bec $start_from will start from 500,if you increment it then it will start from 501